# placing information upon my array gives me "System.String[]" where as the other part of my array gives the desired information. c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, visual-studio

my program is working fine except for one problem "System.String[]" im new to coding in c# and this is my first main assignment upon my course at university.I've asked a few of my friend's as well as the teachers(which was to no avail since they merely said they couldn't help if it was to do with the assignment) I have no idea where i am going wrong within the code.Basically the name input is coming up fine within the list that can be shown, yet the second part of the array merely comes up with "System.String[]" I feel it has a problem do with the code below however, as I have been playing around with it trying to see what is wrong yet can come up with nothing.

```
static void AddDetails()
    {
        string nameInput;
        string licensePlateInput;
        string parkingSlot;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the guest's name");
        nameInput = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("enter the guest's license plate");
        licensePlateInput=Console.ReadLine();
        parkingSlot=Convert.ToString(licensePlate);

        int nextAvailableSlot = FindSlot("");
        if (nextAvailableSlot != -1)
        {
            name[nextAvailableSlot] = nameInput;
            licensePlate[nextAvailableSlot] = parkingSlot;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No empty spots remain");
        }
    }
```

This is the part of my code that allows the user to input the details required and then have it stored.

```
static int FindSlot(string names)
    {
        int result = -1;
        for (int index = 0; index < name.Length;index ++ )
        {
            if (name[index] == names)
            {
                result = index;
                break;
            }
            else if(names == "" && name[index] == null)
            {
                result = index;
                break;
            }
        }

        return result;
```

This is an extension of the first part I feel I should add, since i figured it may help.

```
 static void ListCars()
    {
       for(int index= 0; index < name.Length; index ++)
       {
           if(name [index] != "" && name[index] != null)
           Console.WriteLine(" name {0} car is parked in {1}", name[index], licensePlate[index]);
       }
    }
```

this piece of code is the output (which im sure many of you my know)

Comment: "System.String[]" is the output of calling `ToString` on a `String` array, so obviously that's what you're doing somewhere.  It might have been useful if you'd actually showed us the part that produces that output but at least you know what to look for: somewhere that you're converting the array itself to a `String` instead of getting a `String` from one of the elements.

Comment: `they couldn't help if it was to do with the assignment` Kudos for being honest here, but...if even your teacher has refused to help, doesn't that suggest that you're expected to do this assignment entirely on your own? Anyway, it's clear from your code why you get the string you are getting: you're converting an instance of a `string[]` object to a string -- i.e. `Convert.ToString(licensePlate)` -- and the default conversion in that case is to just give you the type name. But what you really meant to type there I have no idea.

Comment: It looks like what you're trying to do is to find the index of the array that has the license plate (based on `parkingSlot = Convert.ToString(licensePlate);`, but as others have pointed out that won't work.  You'll need to search the array to see if it already has the license plate and what index it is in.

Comment: @PeterDuniho they said they couldn't help due to them being the one's who will be marking the assignment, yet they said we can have outside help, as long as we reference in the documentation where we got the help and how they helped exactly.                                                            I've added more code as well, but im still not sure where I am wrong, as Tim said I've got the licensePlate within the  output, but i feel like I'm missing something but I can't tel what exactly.

Comment: What is `licensePlate` and `name`?

Comment: the second piece information that the user input's within the program, is the licenseplate and the first is name.Plus they are both named as the array's at the beginning of my code.

Comment: so, it's `licensePlate` a `List<string[]>`? That's what I'm asking.

Comment: oh i didnt know that :/ and no its a "static string[] licensePlate; " and then i use it via "licensePlate=new string[10];"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take a stab at this, though I'm not sure I completely grasp the issue.  I think what is throwing things off is this line:

```
parkingSlot = Convert.ToString(licensePlate);
```

As you've found out, the result of this is `System.String[]`, which is not what you want.  You're already getting the next available slot by your call to `FindSlot` in the immediately following line.  I think, if I'm reading the code right, what you really want to do is store the license plate in the `licensePlate` array, so simply use the value the user input that you store in `licensePlateInput`:

```
// Remove this line, as it servers no discernible purpose
//parkingSlot=Convert.ToString(licensePlate);

int nextAvailableSlot = FindSlot("");
if (nextAvailableSlot != -1)
{
    name[nextAvailableSlot] = nameInput;
    // Use the value the user gave for the license plate
    licensePlate[nextAvailableSlot] = licensePlateInput;
}
```

Comment: I just tested it out and it worked.I guess that was just a mistake on my part that I didn't realize was a mistake to begin with till now. Thank you very much Tim

Comment: Happy to help.  Good luck with your assignment and happy coding :)